# Set up portrait video output from Galaxy Nexus

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, mhl

I know that I can hook up my Galaxy Nexus up to my TV, but I'm not able to change the orientation from landscape to portrait.

Is there a setting I'm missing? Or is there a way to do this if my phone is rooted?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this application, it can force screen orientation globally.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.eyesfree.setorientation&hl=en