# HDMI output mirroring in Portrait mode

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, screen, hdmi, external-display

I have an app that works fine in both Landscape and Portrait mode, but it demos best in Portrait mode. I'd like to show this app on a phone with HDMI output (either from MHL, Slimport, or micro-hdmi) and screen mirroring to an external display.

Presently, I have a Samsung Galaxy Nexus. However, as has been pointed out by many, this phone forces the orientation to Landscape when an HDMI display is attached through the MHL adapter (see [Set up portrait video output from Galaxy Nexus](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/27403/1973), [HDMI/MHL possible in portrait mode?](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1881699), [HDMI output, Portrait mode?](http://www.modaco.com/topic/348917-hdmi-output-portrait-mode/))

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can do HDMI Output with mirroring and keep my phone in portrait mode?

Comment: Purchase suggestions are off topic sorry!

Comment: Sorry, I'll rephrase

Comment: Ok, did my best.

Comment: This question, in its current form, is absolutely appropriate here.

Comment: Thanks. I grumbled at first, but this is probably a better question in its current form. I would love a software/configuration fix rather than to purchase a new phone fix. I'm just skeptical about a soft solution so I crafted the first post more about recommendations rather than solutions. But your guidelines are correct. I need a solution, not necessarily a new phone.

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this?

Comment: I never found a solution for my phone (Galaxy Nexus), however I found other phones behaved differently. A Galaxy S3 worked fine in portrait mode on HDMI output. I ended up primarily demoing using droid@screen - http://droid-at-screen.ribomation.com/ - and if I have access to a Galaxy S3 or S4 I use the Samsung specific version of Teamviewer - QuickSupport - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.quicksupport.market.samsung